# How to Install Mathematica 10 on Ubuntu 14.04 Step by Step (I Am Brand Spanking New to Ubuntu)

Tags: downloads, extract

I am trying to install Mathematica 10 on Ubuntu 14.04, I have acquired the program in the downloads folder but I am unable to extract the file upon right clicking and hitting "extract here". I did read around about some of the ways others have gotten Mathematica to run, however being a complete newbie, I did not understand what specific things meant (Mounting to a CD, as well as what commands meant) and many of the steps I had to take to install it. How can I get Mathematica 10 and all its functions to install from start to finish? Also being new, I would like to learn as much as I can to become really effective in Ubuntu, if anyone knows of any resources to get me up to speed could you list them? I would greatly appreciate it! I am starting off with the book Ubuntu an absolute beginners guide. Hopefully I can become effective and independent so I don't have to continue to ask bad questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: sagemath is a open source alternative for mathematica

Answer (score 1):

This article provides a pretty good starting point. 
  [Installing Mathmatica on Unix and Linux](http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/facilities/ComputingFacilities/software/mathematica-6.0/InstallingMathematicaOnUnixAndLinux.html)

For us to be able to help you further you need to provide more exact information on where you're stuck.  It sounds like you downloaded the program.  Do you know the format of the download?  (For example, does it end in .tar or .gz?)  Unlike Microsoft Windows, clicking on stuff in Ubuntu will often lead to more harm than good.

Are you able to open a terminal window to get to a command line?  Can you get to the directory where the file is downloaded?  (Probably /home/[username]/Downloads)

Post more info and we'll get you through it.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for your response! I downloaded the file Mathematica-10.0-Linux.zip. So I am guessing it is a zip file, I think I do know how to get to the command line using ctrl+alt+t. I know the file is located in my downloads folder but other than that I am kind of stuck. I did try to mess around with some of the other suggestion on the different sites but I know I am far to inexperienced to understand what the inputs and the results really meant.

Comment: I did try to resolv mathematica.serc.iisc.ernet.in: and it looks like the problem starts there, my server is unable to find it so I tried to learn a bit more about DNS settings through the link; however I was unable to access that webpage, it says 404 Not Found.

Comment: Inside the file Mathematica-10.0-Linux.zip file is a us_state.shp file. I have no idea what that file is but when I double click on that it says I am unable to extract the file.

Comment: Can you give us a list of all the files in the zip file?  Is the shp file the only file?

Comment: This link is broken

Comment: the  link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Sorry this came extremely late, but ultimately I was able to use the command terminal to acquire mathematica on my computer as Rick Chatham suggested. I acquired a book "The Linux Command Line: A Complete Introduction" by William E. Shotts and by gaining an understanding of the command line and how to use it I was able to install it by changing directories to my downloads and then utilizing sudo apt-get install .

Comment: However, this did require that I download mathematica from a different source, and I did not actually have to complete the mounting process.  Thus one could say that the Mounting problem is still an issue however one can work around it.